# Stored procedure to encrypt data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption

I'm using a store procedure I created:

```
USE [database_name]
GO
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Password_Key
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE PasswordCertificate;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddPassword
    @ID int,
    @Password varchar(50)
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
INSERT INTO .EncryptionTest (ID,Password,Password_Encrypted)
VALUES (@ID,@Password,EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Password_Key')
    , @Password, 1, HashBytes('SHA1', CONVERT(varbinary,@ID))))
GO
```

And when executing:

```
USE [database_name]
GO
EXEC dbo.AddPassword @ID = 1, @Password = 'Test';
GO
```

it adds a row where `ID` = 1, `Password` = 'Test', `Password_Encrypted` = NULL. Why is the last one giving null instead of an encryption of the string 'Test'?

Comment: Do not store passwords in recoverable format.  You must **hash** passwords.

Comment: Did you try selecting instead of inserting? What do you get? Also please don't use variable-length data types (like `varbinary`) without specifying the length.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I want to add a new row of data, not select current ones. But I have managed to select and decrypt currently encrypted password successfully, with similar code.

Comment: @SLaks: What do you mean? Isn't that what I'm doing? The column "Password" is only there for testing atm. However I'm new to encryption in sql so I'm not sure of any of this really.

Comment: I know that. I'm saying in *this* case, in order to *debug*, temporarily change the stored procedure to just perform the *`SELECT`*. Now you can tell if the value is becoming `NULL` before or after the `INSERT`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function.  It should never be possible to decrypt a password.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Ok, I didn't get that. However, after performing `SELECT` it still returns `NULL`, so it's before the `INSERT`.

Comment: @SLaks Ok, I will keep that in mind in future. Right now I'm learning the techniques necessary to do that I suppose.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: I get a value back, FWIW. Are you sure you issued the `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY` in the same scope as executing the stored procedure? Why don't you put the `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY` command inside the stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are executing the procedure from a different scope, or your connection has been severed since creating the procedure. Of course you can't expect that users will open the symmetric key every time they execute the stored procedure, so that should probably be inside the procedure instead of as a step toward creating the procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.AddPassword
  @ID int,
  @Password varchar(50)
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Password_Key
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE PasswordCertificate;

  -- for debugging 101:    
  SELECT EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Password_Key')
    , @Password, 1, HashBytes('SHA1', CONVERT(varbinary(128),@ID)));

  INSERT INTO dbo.EncryptionTest(ID,Password,Password_Encrypted)
  VALUES (@ID,@Password,EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Password_Key')
    , @Password, 1, HashBytes('SHA1', CONVERT(varbinary(128),@ID))));
END
GO
```