# how to export transparent data to encrypted database in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to move/copy transparent data from a database to another database having same tables structure but encrypted. How can i do this job?

Comment: What do you mean with transparent?

Comment: it means data that is not encrypted

Answer (score 0):

In short

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [*YourKeyName*]
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE [*YourCertName*]
GO

DECLARE @Key_Guid AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @Key_Guid = key_guid('*YourKeyName*')

IF( @Key_Guid is not null )
BEGIN
    <*Perform your Insert here*>
END

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY *YourKeyName*
GO
```

Here are a few references worth checking out:
[SQLServerCentral article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic991031-391-1.aspx), [Transparent Data Encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx), [SQL Server Security Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848791.aspx), [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128568/stored-procedure-to-encrypt-data)